# Nessus No host data is available for this scan error

Tags: security, tcp, penetration-testing, nessus

I encountered an error in Nessus result. Error: No host data is available for this scan.

I want to scan ip 192.16x.x.x at Nessus.I scan this ip with nmap.Only 2 tcp port is open in this ip address.And results says host is up.I check my firewall rules.Nothing wrong with that Also I check Nessus logs but I don't see meaningful eror in Nessus's logs

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Nessus is performing host discovery in a different way than your Nmap scan e.g. by using ICMP ping. Have you looked at the Nessus discovery preferences? Under "Preferences" -> "Ping the remote host", uncheck ICMP ping (for example), and enable TCP ping and ARP ping. You may need to play around with this host discovery settings in order to find the correct configuration for you. Note that modifying these settings could increase your scanning times considerably.